# Databases: Insert from multipler servers

Tags: database, postgresql

Rally DB newbie question:

I am trying to insert user records to a DB. The id type could be an autoincrementing serial, or an INT.

How do I insert a record with an ID that is unique, and I can get that ID back, making sure that if the request is handled by multiple application servers, then I don't generate duplicate id's.

e.g.

- Server 1 needs to insert: ( 'John', 'Smith', 25 )
- Server 2 needs to insert: ( 'John', 'Rambo', 25 )

The app server wants the id's of the generated records back. I can't do a select based on attributes  because

1. They could be duplicate
2. It's expensive.

One solution is that each app server also inserts a server id, server update no, combination and then selects on the basis of that.

I feel like this should be such a generic problem that there is would be a much simpler solution.

I'm using PostgreSQL if it matters.

Comment: Hah, if only something being a common and generic problem meant there was a standard solution in SQL. `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. Or the upsert problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With postgres you can use the RETURNING clause to return the value of a column such as

INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (1,2,3) RETURNING id;

Comment: It's not part of the SQL standard but handy to know if you are using postgres ;)

Comment: Thanks again! I was going to mark this as the answer, but would like to wait a bit in case someone has a more 'standard' answer.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what language and tools you're using. That matters, as the standard doesn't really cover this, but many client platforms have their own abstractions.

In particular JDBC has `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()` and `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`.

I don't think there's any equivalent in the ODBC interface. I didn't find one with a quick search, though found that some vendors add it as an extension.

For other clients, it just depends on what you're using. Some ORM layers have their own handling, e.g. Hibernate (and other JPA implementations) handle key generation, as does ActiveRecord (blech), SQLAlchemy, etc.

Otherwise, as Lucas says, you can just use the PostgreSQL extension `RETURNING the_key_column_names_here`. (9.5 should hopefully add `RETURNING PRIMARY KEY` too).

(The SQL spec provides `GENERATED ALWAYS` but as far as I know, no standard way to return the values. Many databases don't implement `GENERATED` anyway.)

Comment: I'm using Scala + ORM + JDBC + Postgre. Lucas's solution works in psql command line, haven't checked if it will work in my project.

Comment: @user247077 If you're using PgJDBC, *please* use the JDBC standard approach with `getGeneratedKeys`. I'd be surprised if your ORM didn't do this for you actually. Which ORM?